# Add field value in the value of another field

Tags: entities, tokens

I'm sorry about the title (I think it's a bit confused :D) I can explain better what I need to do.
I have one product with several fields, among which: title,date, description, price, etc... I would add in a field (for example: description) a value of another field (for example: price). I would also that this setting is applied to content type because that field must always belong to the other field, for every content creation.

I searched on Google and it seems the module Token could be a solution but there are many tutorials (and also different among them), so could you help me. Are appreciated other solution, no just Token.
Thank you

Comment: what is your drupal version?

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Field reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_reference) useful. If you're trying to leverage more functionality, you might like to use [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). But you sound like you want embed the value of one field within the value of another, more like concatenating strings?

Comment: I want something like this: "The dog is [node:field_dog_color], and sky is blue"...so in the page I will have "The dog is brown, and sky is blue"

Answer (score 0):

If what you are aiming to do is include values from other fields within the content of a formatted text field, then you could try using a module that provides token support as an input filter.

[Advanced Text Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_text_formatter) looks like it should do the job (and it has d7/d8 versions). You would then be able to use a [token](https://www.drupal.org/node/390482#token-node) such as `[node:field_price]` within the text and it will be replaced with the value of that field when it is displayed.

It does sound like you should be using tokens, as this is pretty much what they are designed to facilitate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Advanced Text Formatter but the problem is in the Available Token list, I can't see the field that i need. I don't see the tokens like "[node:....]". Where are the tokens about the same content?
[image]